# udev rule not working correctly, probably escaping issue

Tags: bash, vagrant, udev

I try to run an udev rule once a mount is ready on a Vagrant box:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="bdi",ACTION=="add",RUN+="/usr/bin/screen -m -d bash -c 'sleep 5; cd /vagrant/; sudo -E su -c "pm2 start daemon.json" vagrant;'"
```

But the command isn't running properly, since the pm2 doesn't start.
When I execute `/usr/bin/screen -m -d bash -c 'sleep 5; cd /vagrant/; sudo -E su -c "pm2 start daemon.json" vagrant;'` manually it does work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested quotes are surely part of the problem, but the bigger problem is written in the [udev manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html):

> This can only be used for very short-running foreground tasks. Running an event process for a long period of time may block all further events for this or a dependent device. Starting daemons or other long-running processes is not appropriate for udev; the forked processes, detached or not, will be unconditionally killed after the event handling has finished.

So your approach has to be changed. However, let’s suppose the command `pm2 start daemon.json` is appropriately short-running: your question is interesting anyway, because similar quote-nesting problems arise often. So please consider the rest of this answer as an example for the general case.

Instead of going mad with the correct escaping sequences, you can just write

```
RUN+="/usr/bin/screen -m -d bash -c 'sleep 5; cd /vagrant/; sudo -E -u vagrant pm2 start daemon.json"
```

An even simpler solution might be

```
RUN+="/usr/bin/screen -m -d /usr/local/bin/start_vagrant_daemon"
```

where `/usr/local/bin/start_vagrant_daemon` is executable and has the following content

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5
cd /vagrant/
sudo -E -u vagrant pm2 start daemon.json
```

Both solutions require setting up the correct sudo authorizations by editing `/etc/sudoers` or (better) writing them in a new file `/etc/sudoers.d/vagrant_daemon` after enabling `includedir /etc/sudoers.d` in `/etc/sudoers`.